# Read memory by Address - Read more than 255 bytes

Tags: capl, uds

I want to read around 336 bytes of data from NVRAM using Read Memory By Address UDS service. The command I am giving is "23 22 1C 22 01 50", where

1. 0x23 - UDS command for Read Memory By Address
2. 0x22 - Address and Length Format Identifier (Memory
   address parameter - 2 and Memory size parameter 2)
3. 0x1C 0x22 - Memory Address in 2 bytes
4. 0x01 0x50 - Data length to read in 2 bytes (length is 336 bytes)

When I submit the command, I am getting "0x13 Incorrect Message Length or Invalid Format Error".

Can someone help me fixing this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Reference: https://piembsystech.com/uds-protocol/

Comment: Show us the full frame that you are sending in trace window.

Comment: Go Extended session and give command "23 22 1C 22 01 50". Response is 0x13.

Comment: 0x23 is UDS command for Read Memory By Address

Comment: Are you really sending "23 22 1C 22 01 50" in the CAN frame for the UDS request, or are you prefixing with the length 6, like "06 23 22 1C 22 01 50"? UDS tools usually do this automatically, but if you do it as plain CAN frame, you have to take care yourself.

Answer (score 2):

## What NRC 0x13 means

According to ISO 14229-1:2020:
[image: NRC 0x13]

This means:

- SID 0x23 is supported by the server otherwise you would receive NRC 0x11 serviceNotSupported
- Your request has inproper format (it is either too long or too short), in other cases you would receive other NRC (e.g. 0x31 requestOutOfRange). I suspect that address value is not 2 bytes long. It might be 4 bytes long (it depends on the memory type and size), but it is just a guess.

## How to send the request properly

Well we do not know what is the exact format that the server accepts (it depends on memory of the server), but the ISO 14229-1:2020 define SID 0x23 request format as below:
[image: request 0x23 format]

I would try following request:

- 0x22 0x44 0x00 0x00 0x1C 0x22 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x50

where:

- 0x00 0x00 0x1C 0x22 - 4-byte memoryAddress
- 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x50 - memorySize (it is also 4 byte to make sure that addressAndLengthFormatIdentifier is properly interpreted by the server)

## Other options

**Server might have defect(s)** (especially if you succesfully read memory using 2-byte-long address) and **incorrectly display NRC 0x13** or have only **support for certain value of addressAndLenghtFormatIdentifier**. It is hard to judge with 100% certainty though. You would have **provide at least one request with positive response**.
Please do so in the comment and I am going to guide you through the problem.